# how to solve syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line

I have a script ab_script.sh with one line code

```
mv !(hd) "/mediafolder/sd/${PWD##*/}"
```

when running the script in folder `user@debianpc:/mediafolder/sd/01051 dance$` I got

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If I copy this line in terminal and run it as a command, every thing works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!(hd)` is an *extended glob* - you likely have extended globbing enabled by default in your interactive shell, but will need to enable it explicitly using `shopt -s extglob` inside a script. You might also want to consider using the `-t TARGET` form of the `mv` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

mv -t "/mediafolder/sd/${PWD##*/}" -- !(hd)
```

Comment: it works perfect!!